# Localhost address in address bar

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets, localhost

When i type following url

```
http://localhost:8080/helloapp (no slash in last position)
```

in address bar and press enter,it automatically shows

```
http://localhost:8080/helloapp/ (note the slash at last position)
```

Why does this mean?

Is `http://localhost:8080/helloapp` and `http://localhost:8080/helloapp/` same thing?

I am using tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

They are the same thing and this most likely occurs due to a php or apache setting forcing the trailing /

This is a common practice in seo to prevent duplicate content.

Answer (score 0):

Its properly what is apache settings dose. but what makes since to me is that

- The trailing slash should indicate that its a folder
- without it should be indicated as a file